# Override ngOnDestroy

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there any solution to do something like completing observable when the ngOnDestroy is called?
I mean when you have just an component instance, creating new child component is not a solution for me.
I tried to override ngOnDestroy by changing the function in the component **proto** but it seems that angular collect the ngOnDestroy functions and my changed method is not used at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personnaly use this handy piece of code
https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-take-until-destroy
I've done some research and to be honest this approach is the most elegant I could find

Also you don't have to unsubscribe If you make sure that the observable completes  for example by using operators like `take` `takeUntil` etc

If you are creating the component dynamically you can always just pass the instance of the component instead of "this" into the `untilDestroyed` operator

Comment: yes, that package is exactly what I'm trying to achieve, but as I see it was not tested with Ivy and my problem exists when I'm using Ivy

Comment: Yes. I confirm that this work without Ivy compiler by stops when Ivy is enabled :( So any solution how to work also with Ivy?

Comment: I have no idea, to be honest. It seems weird that the rendering engine is influencing it maybe it could be a bug in Ivy?

Comment: I don't think so. It seems that the core collect all ngOnDestroy functions at the beginning and all changes after that won't affect, not like old engine which i think just call ngOnDestroy

Answer (score 0):

Well ngOnDestroy is interface so you are override it all the time... 
You want to complete in the ngOndestroy a source that is never completed ?
You can use takeWhile and pass a boolean

```
// variables section
flag = true;

// somewhere when you want to subscribe
source$
  .pipe(takeWhile(flag)).subscribe(()=>{});

ngDestroy(){
flag = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a subject just for destruction. In ngOnDestroy I fire next() and complete();

```
public destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

somesource$.pipe(
   takeUntil(this.destroy$)
).subscribe(val => //somemething here);

ngOnDestroy():void {
   this.destroy$.next();
   this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

the destroy$ variable could be used outside of the component to see if the component was destroyed or not.

```
someInstanceComponent.destroy$.subscribe(val => //do something);
```

Most of the time I make it private, because I rarely use it outside.